# How can I show different links based on whether a user is logged in or not?

Tags: php

My knowledge of PHP is limited yet growing, though I am stuck with this:

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a> 
<a href="about.php">About</a>
<a href="member_search.php">Members</a> 
<a href="profile.php">View Profile</a>
<a href="login.php">Login</a>
```

I have played with it, though every attempt has not worked. I want it to check whether a user is logged in or not and show the relevant links.

So "Logged In" would have "Home", "Members", "View Profile", "Edit Profile" and "Logout".
"Logged Out" would have "Home", "Register", "Login", etc.

Comment: This totally depends on what framework you are using to log the user in. That framework or library will have a function to determine it

Comment: How do you know a user is logged or not? Are you using sessions, or cookies?

Comment: You should definitively search for basic PHP tutorials, or buy a book about PHP programming. Then, you will be able to figure out such things.

Comment: sessions, though a cookie is being set too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer without seeing how your users are logged in, but I normally use something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
  // do / display stuff for logged in users
}
```

Based on your comment:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
  // do / display stuff for logged in users
}
```

Comment: if($login_check > 0){ 
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     
     $id = $row["id"];   
     session_register('id'); 
     $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
       
     $firstname = $row["firstname"];   
     session_register('firstname'); 
     $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;

     mysql_query("UPDATE members SET last_log_date=now() WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
             
       }

Comment: @Jay Then you can check for for example `isset($_SESSION['firstname'])`

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something along them lines with the session id, just couldn't get it to work.  Changed my nav.php to <?php
 
 if(isset($_SESSION['id']))

{
    include_once "loggedin_nav.php";
}
else
{
  include_once "loggedout_nav.php";
}

 ?> and works fine now, pasted wrong bit in.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($userid > 0) //or whatever criteria
{
  echo "members, view profile, etc"; //put in the actual links
}
else
{
  echo "home, register, login, etc"; //put in the actual links
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sessions in php (see [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)) you can keep a state on the server about the user.

When logging in, for example, you can set `$_SESSION['username']` to the username; meaning you can ask in other parts if there is a username.
For example by using `if (!empty($_SESSION['username']))`.